# Metal: unknown type name float4

Tags: ios, shader, metal

I'm trying to include a header file in a metal shader.
For a prototype like this,

```
float4 someFunction(float4 v);
```

I get this error message,

```
Unknown type name 'float4'; did you mean 'float'?
```

It seems it doesn't understand it's a header for a shader program... Although other errors suggest it does. For instance, if I don't specify the address space here,

```
static float someK = 2.0;
```

I get this error,

```
Global variables must have a constant address space qualifier
```

which can be fixed if I add

```
constant static float someK = 2.0;
```

If I use references, I also get these type of errors,

```
Reference type must include device, threadgroup, constant, or thread address space qualifier
```

So it does look as if the compiler knows it's a shader. Why it doesn't know about float4? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the first two lines in your shader like in this example:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>

using namespace metal;

float4 someFunction(float4 v);

kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]], 
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    float4 color = float4(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
    output.write(color, gid);
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't need to include the metal_stdlib in my header file, but I didn't realize I needed the metal namespace in the header for the vector types... dumb! Thanks again :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- anything changed lately?  It works in a regular header but not in a bridging header to be used from both Swift and Metal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
vector_float4
```

instead.